# Can Roth IRA first time home buyer withdrawals be made up?

Tags: united-states, roth-ira, first-time-home-buyer, withdrawal

If we were to withdraw the annual contributions from our Roth IRAs for the closing costs on a house (we have a 20% down payment, but only recently learned that that's almost $10,000 less than what you *actually* have to put down) would we be able to make up the money we withdrew? Or would we still constrained by the annual $5000 contribution limit?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Whenever one takes a distribution from an IRA, it cannot be put back into an IRA unless one is doing something like (a) take a distribution from the IRA as a rollover where the owner gets cash in hand to be sent to the new IRA custodian within 60 days, and (b) deposit the money with the new IRA custodian within the prescribed time period. For distributions taken by a first-time home purchaser
to buy or rebuild a home, the money can be put back and treated as a rollover
up to 120 days after receiving it (Publication 590, page 51, column 2). Note
also that distributions taken for  first-time homebuying lose their Qualified
Distribution status if not paid to the seller (or bank, for closing
costs etc) within 120 days of receipt of the distribution
(Publication 590, page 51, column 1).
However, one 
*cannot* take a distribution from an IRA, no matter whether the sum comes from contributions, earnings, or previous rollovers, and put the money back into the IRA a few years down the road as having been unnecessarily withdrawn.

What you want to do -- take out some money out of your IRA to buy a house and 
put the money back into the IRA later -- is effectively an *interest-free*
loan from your
IRA (even if you don't call it a loan or think of it as a loan), and you 
are not allowed to do this (except in the special circumstances described above).
On the other hand, unless you have a very
atypical 401k plan, you *can* take a loan from your 401k (you will have to
pay interest, though) and pay it back over several years.
Thus, taking a loan from your 401k
might be something you could consider as an alternative to withdrawing
money from your IRA. But be aware
that there are restrictions on how much you can borrow from your 401k,
and usually you cannot withdraw employer match money, even if it has
vested. Also, the loan becomes immediately due upon termination
of employment, even if the termination was involuntary (i.e. the 
employee was laid off or fired).

Comment: So if I take a contribution out of a Roth IRA it can never be returned? I'm not talking earnings or rollovers

Comment: Yes, and it does not matter whether it is a Roth IRA or a Traditional IRA; you _cannot_ take **any** amount of money as a distribution, regardless of what you choose to call it (contribution/earnings/rollover), and put it back later into the IRA as a _restoration_ of funds previously withdrawn. You _can_, of course, make the usual annual contributions for that year as per the rules that apply then but you cannot contribute more than this amount as a putback of money previously taken as a distribution.

Comment: @littleadv Whenever one takes a distribution from an IRA, it cannot be put back into an IRA unless one is doing something like (a) take a distribution from the IRA as a rollover where the owner gets cash in hand to be sent to the new IRA custodian within 60 days, and (b) deposits the money with the new IRA custodian within the prescribed time period. One _cannot_ take a distribution from an IRA, no matter if the sum comes from contributions, earnings, or previous rollovers and put the money back into the IRA a few years down the road as on the grounds that it was unnecessarily withdrawn.

Comment: @littleadv OK, I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 5):

This answer comes from my interpretation of [Publication 590 (2011), Individual Retirement Arrangements (IRAs)](http://www.irs.gov/publications/p590/index.html) and particularly [What Are Qualified Distributions?](http://www.irs.gov/publications/p590/ch02.html#en_US_2011_publink1000231061) section. Please consult the sources yourself or with the help of a qualified professional before doing anything.

First, note that due to the rollover loophole, you can take out the money and repay it within 60 days. Missing the deadline would mean paying the taxes on the withdrawal in addition to a 10% penalty. As per JoeTaxpayer's notes below, this applies to the earnings on the account only. The contributions themselves can be withdrawn without penalties (thanks, Joe!).

Second, you might qualify to withdraw 10k for a qualified first-home house purchase. Qualified, in this case, would mean first-time home purchase by yourself, your spouse, your child, parent, or grandchild, made within 120 days of withdrawal (see [first home](http://www.irs.gov/publications/p590/ch01.html#en_US_2011_publink1000230922) in the above document).

Finally, nothing is mentioned about the withdrawal affecting your yearly contribution cap. Any new money coming into the account is new money counted towards the contribution cap (except for the 60 day loophole).

To answer your question then: you can make up the money only under the first scenario (60 day loophole). Qualified withdrawals allow you to avoid the penalties, but as far as I can tell, do not affect the contribution cap.

There are a few other details that may depend on your age, reservist status, health, etc. Read the document carefully to see if any of those apply to you.

Comment: There is no 10% penalty for a Roth withdrawal if the withdrawal is from deposits only. i.e. you can always withdraw your deposit penalty free. Since Roth is post tax money, that withdrawal of deposits has no tax due either. +1 for trying and friendly welcome to SE.

Comment: "Repayments under the above two exceptions are treated as repayments." So you are saying that if a taxpayer withdraws $10K worth of Roth contributions for a qualified first-time house purchase, then that money can be put back later (even after the 120-day period (Pub. 590, page 51, column 2) has expired?)

Comment: "First home in this case would mean one of you has not owned a home in the last two years." No, *both* spouses must meet the requirement.

Comment: Er, not quite. Money taken out as a rollover must be deposited with the new IRA custodian within 60 days or else it becomes an unqualified distribution subject to penalties etc. I am not sure whether it is possible to send the money back to the same IRA custodian from whom it was received. On the other hand, it seems that money taken out for a qualified first-home purchase can be put back into the same account within 120 days if not used for the purchase. 120 days to use it for the purpose it was withdrawn or to be restored back into the account.

Comment: From everything I read you can return the money within 60 days to the same account. See [this](http://www.chicagotribune.com/business/yourmoney/chi-ym-cruz-1007oct07,0,4813127.story) and [this](http://www.smartmoney.com/retirement/planning/tapping-your-ira-penalty-free-7958/).

Comment: The publication simply states "It must be used to pay qualified acquisition costs before the close of the 120th day after the day you received it." I cannot find anything to support the idea that you can return the qualified home distribution to the account.

Comment: Ok found it at 590, page 51, column 2, as per your post.

Comment: @denten - From Pub 590 p22 - "You can withdraw, tax free, all or part of the assets from one traditional IRA if you reinvest them within 60 days in the same or another traditional IRA." I was about to suggest those articles were in error, as i recall as Dilip does, that there was a requirement to deposit the funds to a different account.