# Can you replace Roth IRA contributions that you withdrew?

Tags: united-states, roth-ira, contribution, withdrawal

If I withdraw my Roth IRA contributions from previous years, is it possible to ever replace that money in the Roth IRA?

Comment: No, you cannot. For some details, see [this question](http://money.stackexchange.com/q/20411/5760). I am voting to close this one as a duplicate.

Comment: I would recommend changing the title and making it more generic if you were to close this one.  I saw that one and didn't look at it as I thought it was specifically for first time home purchases.

Comment: The answers in the question referred to do give additional details as to what the rules are for first-time home buyers, but, those rules are laxer than those which must be followed if you withdraw your contributions from your Roth IRA. As littleadv's answer notes and as the answers to the other question also discuss, you have 60 days to roll over withdrawals into a Roth IRA.  A literal interpretation of Pub 590, (p. 68, col. 2, first sentence about rollovers) seems to say that you cannot put the money _back_ but must invest in a different IRA.

Comment: @DilipSarwate This isn't a duplicate question.  The other question is a specialization of *this* canonical question.  We'll keep this open.  Suggest you post the detail in your second comment as an answer here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only within 60 days of the withdrawal.

Comment: It almost reads as if I did this 60 day rollover option I would have to chose a different ira custodian.  Would you agree with that?

Comment: I don't think you have to chose a different custodian.

Comment: "This essentially means you can withdraw money from your IRA tax- and penalty-free as long as you put it back into the same or a different IRA within 60 days." - from http://www.schwab.com/public/schwab/resource_center/expert_insight/ask_carrie/credit_debt/can_you_borrow_from_your_ira.html - @littleadv is correct, same acct is fine.